# android-support-v4.jar error on examplelistactivity by jeremy

Tags: android

http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-rNtbng1j0CU/Ul-CGs1mh4I/AAAAAAAAAN8/RvokLlMM7GM/s1600/123.PNG

I am trying to integrate the Sliding Menu and ActionbarSherlock? I have tried http://boroniatechnologies.com/category/blog/ but it's is useless the error keep coming up. Tried to add a new jar but it doesn't work. Can anyone do a step by step tutorial on this for me? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Add a `libs` folder in your project
- Add the support Library
- Add library to build path

Right click on project >Properties>Java Build path >Check the support library

- and finally clean the project

Comment: did that and still have this error [2013-10-17 17:14:34 - ExampleListActivity]  SHA-1: 4a6be13368bb64c5a0b0460632d228a1a915f58f
[2013-10-17 17:14:34 - ExampleListActivity] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies

Comment: okhay Jar Mismatch means there are two jar files of different versions

one in your project and the other in your library project .
So what you can do is download a fresh copy of the library and paste it in both the projects..

Comment: if it helped you please accept the answer ...so that it helps someone else as well.. :) :)